# Scala.js - Inject contents of css file into an inline <style> tag

Tags: css, reactjs, inject, scala.js, inline-styles

I am trying to build a web app (in Scala.js and ScalaReact) which is going to be added as a self-contained widget inside a larger web app, over which I have no control (cannot write things into the  tag).

My app is going to contain a few pages with different CSS styles but also a collection of generic styles, which need to be loaded together with the widget.

My only option is to add inline  tags dynamically but I can't find a way to read the contents of a CSS file and dump it in the  tag at compilation time.

I've tried using ScalaCSS which can do the trick but its DSL is incomplete and doesn't meet my requirements even closely.

How can I trick Scala.js into generating  tags with contents taken from local CSS files?

Comment: I have looked at this question several times now and am still puzzled: Couldn't you just include the static CSS file with a <link> tag?

Comment: The contents of my app (html and scripts) are injected within another page so aadding tags inside <head>, outside my own DOM is not an option. My solution was to generate inline a style tag with an @include statement but I wanted something that would allow me not to depend on an external path i.e. injecting css content directly

Answer (score 1):

It is probably easiest to use the help of sbt to generate an object containing the CSS file as a string literal:

```
sourceGenerators in Compile <+= Def.task {
  val sourceFile = ???  // path to your file
  val targetFile = (sourceManaged in Compile).value / "CssHolder.scala"
  val css = IO.read(sourceFile).replaceAllLiterally("$", "$$")
  val scalaCode =
    s"""object CssHolder { final val css = raw\"\"\"$css\"\"\" } """

  IO.write(targetFile, scalaCode)

  Seq(targetFile)
}
```

Now in you code, you can simply refer to `CssHolder.css` and put it inside a `<style>` tag. Note that most IDEs will complain about this, since they do not know about source generators.

Comment: Hi @gzm0, thank you for your answer. It worked ok for me to generate the CssHolder.scala file but when I try to complie, it throws an error at the line where I'm trying to import CssHolder (let's say in Index.scala):  '.' expected but ';' found. The generated scala file look ok and the syntax validates alright. What could I be missing?

Comment: This sounds like the code that imports CssHolder has a syntax error. If you don't get an error in `CssHolder.scala` your generation code is fine.

Comment: I've tried generating a scala object with val css = "foo" but I got the same result so I don't think it's a syntax error really.

Comment: Do you have an example project where I can reproduce the error?